# 16.04 server: enabling LDAP authentication causes systemd-logind to fail

Tags: server, login, authentication, ldap

I'm stumped here, sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I had a 16.04 server authenticating against LDAP that stopped working last time I ran updates, and I built a clean 16.04 server from scratch, ran standard updates, and it works fine until I enable LDAP authentication. I can disable LDAP and then it works again.

```
me@myserver:/etc# systemctl status systemd-logind.service
● systemd-logind.service - Login Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Tue 2016-07-12 15:13:07 EDT; 19s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-logind.service(8)
           man:logind.conf(5)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
 Main PID: 2106 (systemd-logind)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 228.0K
      CPU: 2ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-logind.service
           └─2106 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind

Jul 12 15:13:07 myserver systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
```

It will churn for a while, fail, then try starting again in endless loops. I can log in to a local account but it takes a long time.

```
me@myserver:/etc# systemd-analyze blame
Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.
```

Meanwhile journalctl -xe returns its own more verbose loop:

```
me@myserver:/etc# journalctl -xe
-- Subject: Unit systemd-logind.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-logind.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 12 15:16:27 myserver systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 12 15:16:27 myserver systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 12 15:16:27 myserver systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Jul 12 15:16:27 myserver systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-logind.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-logind.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 12 15:16:27 myserver systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-logind.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-logind.service has begun starting up.
Jul 12 15:16:52 myserver systemd-logind[2134]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jul 12 15:16:52 myserver systemd-logind[2134]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jul 12 15:16:52 myserver dbus[1012]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jul 12 15:16:52 myserver systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 12 15:16:52 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
```

I've got two dozen or so 14.04 servers working fine w/ LDAP, same config.

I've tried manually restarting systemd-logind but it fails.

Any ideas? TIA.

(ETA: just built the exact same system on 14.04 and LDAP authentication works fine.)

Adding dpkg.log info:
There's a lot of noise in this file, so not sure what's relevant and useful, but here's what appears to be the terminal lines of processing for related packages:

```
2016-07-11 13:52:08 status installed libldap-2.4-2:amd64 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3
2016-07-11 14:11:40 status installed libldap-2.4-2:amd64 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.1
2016-07-11 15:02:45 status installed libnss-ldap:amd64 265-3ubuntu2
2016-07-11 15:02:45 status installed ldap-auth-client:all 0.5.3
2016-07-11 15:02:45 status installed ldap-auth-config:all 0.5.3
2016-07-11 15:02:45 status installed libpam-ldap:amd64 184-8.7ubuntu1
2016-07-11 15:04:12 status installed ldap-utils:amd64 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.1
```

My LDAP server is elsewhere; this server only needs to authenticate against it as a client. The config files at /etc/ldap.conf and /etc/ldap/ldap.conf are identical and appear to have not changed between 14.04 and 16.04

It's worth noting that although LDAP authentication is not working, I can successfully do an ldapsearch query against the LDAP server.

Comment: Can you look in `/var/log/dpkg.log` and see if any related packages were updated? If so can you add that information to the question? thanks!

Comment: Here is a full guided configuration of LDAP in Ubuntu 16.04, including details of the configuration file `/etc/ldap.conf`. They might be of help. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322679

Comment: added dpkg.log info. server is only an ldap client, but configs all match instructions and do not seem to have changed from 14.04

Comment: Could you try downgrading `libldap-2.4-2` and `ldap-utils` back down to version `2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3`?

Comment: Downgraded those two packages, behavior remains unchanged. :( Thanks for the suggestion, though!  

For (probably not useful) reference, the working 14.04 system has 2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3 for both packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem with my 16.04 desktop clients.

Finally resolved replacing the libnss-ldap package with **libnss-ldapd**.

Seems the same issue as in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnss-ldap/+bug/1024475

**EDIT**: more info about these packages from the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/NSS):

> There are currently two packages available to configure NSS lookups
>   through LDAP: the libnss-ldap package and the libnss-ldapd package.
>   Which one to choose depends on the needs. In general libnss-ldapd is
>   simpler but newer and libnss-ldap is more mature but more complex.
>   Also **libnss-ldap has some known issues with serving host information
>   and lookups during boot which should be addressed in libnss-ldapd**. In
>   addition, libnss-ldap breaks setuid programs (su, sudo) when using
>   LDAP+SSL

Comment: Ah, thank you! Was beginning to wonder if it was just me. Will try that! (-:

Answer (score 3):

A way to prevent this problem is to make sure the `nss_initgroups_ignoreusers` parameter - in `/etc/ldap.conf` (or `/etc/libnss-ldap.conf`, depending on your system) - is populated with all the (local) users in `/etc/passwd`:

```
NSS_IGNOREUSERS="$(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's|,$||')"
sed -i "s|^nss_initgroups_ignoreusers.*|nss_initgroups_ignoreusers ${NSS_IGNOREUSERS}|" /etc/ldap.conf
```

This way, when the system boots and users/groups name services are queried to start the local services, no more 'nss_ldap: Can't contact LDAP server' will be issued (since the corresponding local user/group are ignored by NSS LDAP).

(this issue has been around for years, independently from systemd)