# LDAP authentication on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, authentication, ldap, sssd

## context

I'm trying to configure LDAP authentication on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

## steps to reproduce

In order to do that, I followed the following steps:

- `apt install sssd libpam-sss libnss-sss`
- create a `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` with the following content

  ```
  [sssd]
  debug_level = 0x01E0
  services = nss, pam
  config_file_version = 2
  domains = default

  [nss]
  debug_level = 0x01E0

  [pam]
  debug_level = 0x01E0
  offline_credentials_expiration = 60

  [domain/default]
  debug_level = 0x01E0
  ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
  cache_credentials = True
  ldap_search_base = ou=department,o=company,c=country
  id_provider = ldap
  auth_provider = ldap
  chpass_provider = ldap
  access_provider = ldap
  ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.company.country
  ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=***,o=company,c=country
  ldap_default_authtok = *****
  ldap_tls_reqcert = try
  ldap_search_timeout = 50
  ldap_network_timeout = 60
  ldap_access_order = filter
  ldap_access_filter = (objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
  ```
- made sure that only root has access to the config file:

  ```
  chown root:root /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
  chmod 0600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
  ```
- restarted the service

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart sssd
  ```
- made sure that the service is started correctly: `sudo systemctl status sssd`

  ```
  ● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-01-19 08:26:45 UTC; 1h 1min ago
  Main PID: 24043 (sssd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 2316)
  CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
           ├─24043 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
           ├─24064 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/sssd_be --domain default --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           ├─24070 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           └─24071 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

  Jan 19 08:26:45 ubuntu1804.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon...
  Jan 19 08:26:45 ubuntu1804.localdomain sssd[24043]: Starting up
  Jan 19 08:26:45 ubuntu1804.localdomain sssd[be[24064]: Starting up
  Jan 19 08:26:45 ubuntu1804.localdomain sssd[24070]: Starting up
  Jan 19 08:26:45 ubuntu1804.localdomain sssd[24071]: Starting up
  Jan 19 08:26:45 ubuntu1804.localdomain systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
  ```

## troubleshooting steps

### logs

When I look at the logs, everything seem to be fine:

```
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [sss_names_init_from_args] (0x0100): Using re [(?P<name>[^@]+)@?(?P<domain>[^@]*$)].                                                                                                                                     │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [sss_fqnames_init] (0x0100): Using fq format [%1$s@%2$s].                                                                                                                                                                │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [start_service] (0x0100): Queueing service default for startup                                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [client_registration] (0x0100): Received ID registration: (%BE_default,1)                                                                                                                                                │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [mark_service_as_started] (0x0100): Now starting services!                                                                                                                                                               │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [start_service] (0x0100): Queueing service nss for startup                                                                                                                                                               │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [start_service] (0x0100): Queueing service pam for startup                                                                                                                                                               │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [client_registration] (0x0100): Received ID registration: (pam,1)                                                                                                                                                        │
└(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd] [client_registration] (0x0100): Received ID registration: (nss,1)                                                                                                                                                        │
┌(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [monitor_common_send_id] (0x0100): Sending ID: (nss,1)                                                                                                                                                              │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [sss_names_init_from_args] (0x0100): Using re [(?P<name>[^@]+)@?(?P<domain>[^@]*$)].                                                                                                                                │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [sss_fqnames_init] (0x0100): Using fq format [%1$s@%2$s].                                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [sss_names_init_from_args] (0x0100): Using re [(((?P<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?P<name>.+$))|((?P<name>[^@]+)@(?P<domain>.+$))|(^(?P<name>[^@\\]+)$))].                                                                      │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [sss_fqnames_init] (0x0100): Using fq format [%1$s@%2$s].                                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [responder_set_fd_limit] (0x0100): Maximum file descriptors set to [8192]                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0100): Data Provider does not support this operation.                                                                                                                                         │
└(Tue Jan 19 09:28:56 2021) [sssd[nss]] [id_callback] (0x0100): Got id ack and version (1) from Monitor                                                                                                                                                     │
┌(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0100): Trying to resolve service 'LDAP'                                                                                                                                        │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_files_send] (0x0100): Trying to resolve A record of 'ldap.company.country' in files                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [set_server_common_status] (0x0100): Marking server 'ldap.company.country' as 'resolving name'                                                                                                                      │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_files_send] (0x0100): Trying to resolve AAAA record of 'ldap.company.country' in files                                                                                                        │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_dns_query] (0x0100): Trying to resolve A record of 'ldap.company.country' in DNS                                                                                                              │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [set_server_common_status] (0x0100): Marking server 'ldap.company.country' as 'name resolved'                                                                                                                       │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_cli_auth_step] (0x0100): expire timeout is 900                                                                                                                                                        │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [simple_bind_send] (0x0100): Executing simple bind as: cn=***,o=company,c=country                                                                                                       │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [fo_set_port_status] (0x0100): Marking port 636 of server 'ldap.company.country' as 'working'                                                                                                                       │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [set_server_common_status] (0x0100): Marking server 'ldap.company.country' as 'working'                                                                                                                             │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [be_run_online_cb] (0x0080): Going online. Running callbacks.                                                                                                                                               │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [be_ptask_enable] (0x0080): Task [SUDO Smart Refresh]: already enabled                                                                                                                                      │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_sudo_load_sudoers_done] (0x0040): Received 0 sudo rules                                                                                                                                               │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:29:06 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [be_ptask_enable] (0x0080): Task [SUDO Full Refresh]: already enabled
```

When I try to login with a local account (vagrant), the authentication is OK:

```
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): command: SSS_PAM_OPEN_SESSION                                                                                                                                                            │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): domain: not set                                                                                                                                                                          │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): user: vagrant                                                                                                                                                                            │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): service: sshd                                                                                                                                                                            │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): tty: ssh                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): ruser: not set                                                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): rhost: 10.0.2.2                                                                                                                                                                          │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): authtok type: 0                                                                                                                                                                          │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): newauthtok type: 0                                                                                                                                                                       │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): priv: 1                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): cli_pid: 24354                                                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): logon name: vagrant                                                                                                                                                                      │
└(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[pam]] [filter_responses] (0x0100): [pam_response_filter] not available, not fatal.                                                                                                                                        │
┌(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [vagrant@default] in cache                                                                                                                                 │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:39:52 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [vagrant@default] in cache
```

so far, so good...

Now, when I try to login with an ldap user, I get a permission denied error:

```
(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_cmd_authenticate] (0x0100): entering pam_cmd_authenticate                                                                                                                                                      │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): command: SSS_PAM_AUTHENTICATE                                                                                                                                                            │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): domain: not set                                                                                                                                                                          │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): user: jaep                                                                                                                                                                               │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): service: sshd                                                                                                                                                                            │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): tty: ssh                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): ruser: not set                                                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): rhost: 10.0.2.2                                                                                                                                                                          │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): authtok type: 1                                                                                                                                                                          │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): newauthtok type: 0                                                                                                                                                                       │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): priv: 1                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): cli_pid: 24480                                                                                                                                                                           │
│(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): logon name: jaep                                                                                                                                                                         │
└(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[pam]] [filter_responses] (0x0100): [pam_response_filter] not available, not fatal.                                                                                                                                        │
┌(Tue Jan 19 09:42:27 2021) [sssd[be[default]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [jaep@default] in cache
```

## getent

I found the following question: [Enabling OpenLdap authentication in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283787/enabling-openldap-authentication-in-ubuntu-18-04)

it suggests to use the `getent passwd` to list accounts on the machine.
In my case, the vagrant user appears:

```
vagrant:x:1000:1000:vagrant,,,:/home/vagrant:/bin/bash
```

while my ldap user does not show up.

it looks like the system is not even trying to authenticate me against the LDAP directory.

What am I missing?
How can I get to authenticate against LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this however I found that until I added the two vars into the sssd.conf sssd wasn't able to connect:

```
--sssd.conf--
[domain/stuff]
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/ssl/certs
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ssl/certs/my_root_ca.crt
```